# Certificado SSL

Tags: git, github, certificado-digital

Bom dia a todos, estou tentando clonar um projeto do github para minha maquina, mas este sempre aparece o seguinte erro:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/jcfonsecagit/repositorio.git/': SSL certificate
>   problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Pensei que fosse por falta de configurações come e-mail, usuário, e até mesmo a chave. Efetuei todas as configurações e tentei novamente clonar, criei ate uma nova chave, mas ainda assim a mensagem continua. Alguém pode me ajudar, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo digita assim no terminal:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu certo. qual é a desse comando?

Comment: Ele desabilita a verificação de SSL, amigo se puder colocar como resposta correta agradeço.